# What does worst-case gate capacitance mean in a MOS transistor?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, capacitance

I have searched the statement; MOS worst-case gate capacitance in various forms but no avail.

Keep in mind I'm a student. The course I am taking has no reference material. With note slides with pictures and formulas.

The only "formulas" that are provided for gate capacitance are:

[image]

[image]

There is no text on what does a worst case gate capacitance per unit area means. Yet there is a homework question on it. There was no mention of it in class.

What does it mean? And how do you judge it is worst-case?

Comment: A large gate capacitance will cause a FET to switch more slowly and increase switching loss.  I would assume the "worst case" gate capacitance is the largest value the transistor can have.

Comment: _"The course I am taking has no reference material."_ You should seriously consider better quality courses!

Comment: Also need to show the transistor model to see where Cj and Ceq is

Comment: In general, "worst case" means "the worst it can get" -- which means you need to know what worse is.  In the case of gate capacitance, that's bigger -- circuit designers would love to get their hands on FETs with zero-capacitance gates.

Comment: i think of a data sheet's min and max and typical specs for a mosfet; worst case would be max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst case gate capacitance is simply the max. gate capacitance specified in its datasheet. The highest value is considered the worst because higher means slower to switch on/off from the same drive circuit.

This maximum value will allow for variations in material properties and temperature.